# How to use the ExtensionPoint in UI5

Tags: sapui5

I need to create 2 view which has 2 parts 1st part of the view is common for both the views and the 2nd part is different for both the views, so I was thinking to make 2nd part as the extension point so that both the views can have his own view to the 2nd part. I think I made you understand :)

So I wrote my parent view as below

```
<table:TreeTable  selectionMode="MultiToggle"
    enableSelectAll="false" rowHeight="40" firstVisibleRowChanged="onFirstVisibleRowChanged"
    toggleOpenState="onOpenParent">
     ....

</table:TreeTable>
<core:ExtensionPoint name="part2"></core:ExtensionPoint>
```

Here the ext point **part2** I need use in child views.

How to use the points in XML View?

tried like this

```
<mvc:XMLView viewName="parent.view.Name">
<core:ExtensionPoint name="part2">
        <mvc:XMLView viewName="child.view.Name">
        </mvc:XMLView>
    </core:ExtensionPoint>
</mvc:XMLView>
```

in this it thinks its a aggregation :(

Answer (score 0):

Do you think [SplitApp](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/docs/api/symbols/sap.m.SplitApp.html) is the choice for you?

Another option would be a [fragment](http://scn.sap.com/community/developer-center/front-end/blog/2015/05/21/use-of-fragments-in-sapui5-reusability)

Comment: sorry @Shidai i need to do some thing like Extending the XML/JS View where child view will have his own View controls